# How do I make wildcards work in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a bash script:

```
#~/bin/sh
mkdir metaphlan2

echo "Profiling from reads"
echo
samples="CFC280618 MFC280618 SBW280618"
for x in ${samples}
do metaphlan2.py ${x}_S*_R1_001.fastq.gz,${x}_S*_R2_001.fastq.gz --bowtie2out metaphlan2/\${x}.bowtie2.bz2 -o metaphlan2/\${x}.metaphlan2.txt --input_type multifastq --nproc 10 
done
```

Where the `*` is supposed to represent any character.

However when I ran my script in terminal, I got the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SBW280618_S*_R1_001.fastq.gz'
```

Will anyone be kind enough to help please?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. The error message shows a different command than the one you have submitted, containing literal parentheses, which have special meaning in Bash. Please post the actual code.

Comment: Please update the question instead of putting edits in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` is not supposed to represent any character, but to expand the string to match something that exists by substituting the `*` for whatever is needed.

Unfortunately, you are trying to expand

```
${x}_S*_R1_001.fastq.gz,${x}_S*_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

and probably you don't have any file called that way. I'm pretty sure you have **two** files, one called `${x}_S*_R1_001.fastq.gz` and another called `${x}_S*_R2_001.fastq.gz`. The comma in the middle make that string to be considered a single string/file.

You need to separate the files between them with spaces. If that's not possible, you will have to expand both files independently and finally generate the string your binary needs.

Try with this second option:

```
#/bin/sh
mkdir metaphlan2

echo "Profiling from reads"
echo
samples="CFC280618 MFC280618 SBW280618"
for x in ${samples}
do
    fq1="${x}"_S*_R1_001.fastq.gz
    fq2="${x}"_S*_R2_001.fastq.gz
    metaphlan2.py "$fq1,$fq2" --bowtie2out metaphlan2/\${x}.bowtie2.bz2 -o metaphlan2/\${x}.metaphlan2.txt --input_type multifastq --nproc 10
done
```

Comment: Dear Poshi,

Thanks for your help! But unfortunately, I am still getting this error:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CFC280618 MFC280618 SBW280618_S*_R1_001.fastq.gz'

Comment: Oops... usually quoting everything is the way to go. In that case, you are interested in getting the different samples separated by the spaces, so we have to avoid those quotes. Check the updated answer.

Comment: It would be better to store the samples in an array instead of a string, but it should work anyways.